# How to do toggle between functions?

Tags: javascript, toggle, togglebutton

```
HTML

<button type="button" class="btn" name="showAllBtn" onClick="showAllSteps()">Show all</button>

JS

function showAllSteps()
{
//code  
}
function nextStep()

{
//code
}
```

If i click on show all button it should toggle between these two functions.Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: So you wan't the click listener to alternate between ```showAllSteps()``` and ```nextStep()``` whenever the button is clicked?

Comment: yes whenever the button is clicked,i want it to toggle between those functions

Comment: Couldn't you add onDblClick = "next step();" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) for storing the click state,

```
document.querySelector("button[name='showAllBtn']").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var state = this.dataset.clicked;
  state = state || true;
  ((state) ? showAllSteps : nextStep)();
  this.dataset.clicked = !state;  
},false);
```

Edit: `True`/`false` seems to cause some problem with the above code. Hence I have made some tweak above and given it below.

```
document.querySelector("button[name='showAllBtn']").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var state = this.dataset.clicked;
  state = typeof state == "undefined" ? "Y" : state;
  ((state == "Y") ? showAllSteps : nextStep)();
  this.dataset.clicked = (state == "Y") ? "N" : "Y"; 
},false);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9rfxf83w/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showAllSteps() {
    alert('showAllSteps');    
    expectedFunc = function() { nextStep(); };
}

function nextStep() {
    alert('nextStep');     
    expectedFunc = function() { showAllSteps(); };
}

function toggleFunction() {
    expectedFunc();
}

var expectedFunc = function() { showAllSteps(); };
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn" name="showAllBtn" onclick="toggleFunction()">Show all</button>
```

JsFiddle here (updated for IE): https://jsfiddle.net/t0g6ayhq/2/

Comment: Thanks! can you explain what this is =() => ??do you have any explanation for this??

Comment: @RamyaSelvaraj this is how you affect a function to a variable so it can be invoke later. Here is an interesting post on that matter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: It is not working in IE...what is the replacement for this code in IE?

Comment: @RamyaSelvaraj check the updated fiddle, it is now working in IE ... seems like it doesn't like the arrow function expression.